# Change filter value on a view on multiple libraries

Tags: 2013, document-library, powershell, view

Is it possible to change a value on all libraries within a site.  I have multiple libraries where the term name in the store has been changed.  However in libraries I have documents tagged with the old term.  The view the library is looking for this old term.  Can I use powershell to change the filter value on mass for all libraries.  Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do here.

Get a ref to the Term store and terms:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://yoursite
$web = $site.OpenWeb("yourweb")
$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $site

$list = $web.lists["Documents"]

$field = $list.Fields["TargetField"]
$termStoreId = $field.SspId
$termsetId = $field.TermSetId.ToString()
$termstore = $session.TermStores[$termStoreId]
$termSet = $termstore.GetTermSet($termsetId)
$terms = $termset.GetAllTerms()
```

Once you have that you need to find the items to replace. You need to get the WSSId of the original term:

```
$term = $terms | where {$_.Name -eq 'YourOldTerm'}
$WSSId = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]::GetWssIdsOfTerm($site, $termstoreid, $termsetId,$term.Id, $false, 1)
```

Now that you have that you can issue a query to find your items:

```
$caml = "<Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' Name='YourFieldName' />
                <Value Type='Integer'>$WSSId</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Where>"
    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"
    $query.Query = $caml
    $items = $list.GetItems($query)
```

Loop through the $items get the taxonomy field for each $item:

```
$fld = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$item.Fields["YourFieldName"]
```

Get your new value from the original $terms:

```
$newValue = $terms | where {$_.Name -eq 'New Value'}
```

And finally set it:

```
$fld.SetFieldValue($folder.Item, $newValue)
$item.Update()
```

Ideally you should wrap all this in a function. If you don't understand anything let me know and I can do just that when I get some spare time.